# Laravel Vuejs, problema al añadir dos stores diferentes mi Vuex (y a demas de un error de nombre de metodo duplicado)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

tengo el codigo siguiente :

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


//support vuex
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

// Vuex s personalizados
// import PropuestaStore from "./components/Store/PropuestaStore"

export const   PropuestaStore =
    {
        state:{
            test:'Soy PropuestaStore'
        },
        getters:{
            test(state){
                return state.test;
            }
        }
    };
export const   UserStore =
    {
        state:{
            test:'Soy UserStore'
        },
        getters:{
            test(state){
                return state.test;
            }
        }
    };
//Store Main (el que llama a los demas stores)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      propuesta:PropuestaStore,
      user:UserStore
    },
  })



/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

// Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('propuesta-crud', require('./components/Propuesta/PropuestaCRUD.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store
});
```

Con esto pretendo tener varios Stores para tener una organizacion: en este caso por un lado el store de **propuestas** y otro de **usuarios**, pero ambos tienen un getter llamado **test()** el cual me devuelve el **state de cada store** , que pasa? que al llamarlo desde un componente :`this.$store.getters.test` me dice : `[vuex] duplicate getter key: test`. Perfecto, pero **entonces si creo varios stores para organizarlo y modularlo correctamente no podria tener ningun metodo que se repitiese en toda la app?** No tiene ningun sentido no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado te falta poner [namespacing](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) en el módulo y por otro lado estás llamando mal el método:

```
export const PropuestaStore =
    {
        namespaced: true,
        state:{
            test:'Soy PropuestaStore'
        },
        getters:{
            test(state){
                return state.test;
            }
        }
    };

export const   UserStore =
    {
        namespaced: true,
        state:{
            test:'Soy UserStore'
        },
        getters:{
            test(state){
                return state.test;
            }
        }
    };

..............

this.$store.getters['propuesta/test'];
// o
this.$store.getters['user/test'];
```